# Force a stop to map animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When a user clicks a map and drag it around before releasing the mouse button, the map continues to move for a while.
Is there a way to force a stop to that sliding motion?

Run the code snippet below and click the buttons while the map is still. Works perfect.

Now set the map in motion and click one of the buttons before the map has stopped. The map animation continues when the new route is being displayed.

I don't want to disable the dragging option completely, like so

```
map.setOptions({ draggable: false });
```

I would like to force a stop to any motion the map has, so it doesn't propagate into the next route being displayed.

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var buttonClick = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, this);
  };

  var btnRoute1 = document.getElementById("btnRoute1");
  btnRoute1.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);

  var btnRoute2 = document.getElementById("btnRoute2");
  btnRoute2.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btnRoute1);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btnRoute2);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, clickedButton) {
  var origin = clickedButton.getAttribute("data-origin");
  var destination = clickedButton.getAttribute("data-destination");
  directionsService.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: "DRIVING"
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === "OK") {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
 } else {
      window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
 }
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <button id="btnRoute1" data-origin="chicago, il" data-destination="st louis, mo">Chicago -> St Louis</button>
    <button id="btnRoute2" data-origin="chicago, il" data-destination="los angeles, ca">Chicago -> Los Angeles</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your map is still dragging after your let go, it sounds like there may be an issue with your map code. add your code to a jsfiddle so we can see what we're working with.

Comment: When do you fire the dragend event is the question. I don't think there is any option to modify that behaviour or api event to know when you released your mouse button and force the map to stop panning.

Comment: Added code snippet